# Mailshake API Integration in php

Tags: php

I am new in mail shake API integration in php.So I want to integrate mail shake using php.I read the documentation and follow git hub but not found the way "how to integrate?".Please assist me.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with CURL, here i have placed sample code with CURL

```
curl "https://api.mailshake.com/2017-04-01/recipients/add" \
  -u "my-api-key:" \
  -d campaignID=1 \
  -d addAsNewList=true \
  -d listOfEmails="\"John Doe\" <john@doe.com>, \"Jane Doe\" <jane@doe.com>"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this one.

```
<pre>
    &lt;?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.mailshake.com/2017-04-01/recipients/add? 
        campaignID=1&addAsNewList=true&listOfEmails=bikash%40cleonix.net",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "my-api-key: 0ea58c25-389f-427b-9e72-50a58b8319e7"   
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
</pre>
```

Comment: Good job on sharing your API key!